# Installing MySQL system tables... ERROR: 1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1?

Tags: mysql, installation, mysql5, osx-leopard

I was setting up a Rails 3 environment on my local machine with MySql5 following this tutorial: http://blog.openrain.com/2008/08/20/setup-ruby-and-rails-on-osx/.

When I run the below command:
sudo -u mysql mysql_install_db5

I get the following error.

## --------

Installing MySQL system tables...
ERROR: 1136  Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
101010 22:40:53 [ERROR] Aborting

101010 22:40:53 [Note] /opt/local/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete

## ---------

Please help me resolve this.

Thanks
Vishal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that there were lingering files and sql tables from my previous installation.

I emptied the following directory  '/opt/local/var/db/mysql5' and then executed 'sudo -u mysql mysql_install_db5' successfully.